# Select data from query without column names

Tags: sql, vba, select, excel

I'm using SQL in VBA to populate a spread sheet, but when I do this I get the data including the column headers. I am trying to find away to pull just the information out and no column names.

For example,

```
id name job
0  Tom  Repair
1  Bob  Tech
```

instead I want,

```
0  Tom  Repair
1  Bob  Tech
```

Comment: How are you using SQL/executing the query?

Comment: +1 on Alex's question: there might be half a dozen ways you could be doing this...

Comment: Another +1, for example, the Excel command CopyFromRecordset does not return column (field) names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can have no column headers... Note: this is mysql, not sure about your dbms, but this is the closest I got:

```
SELECT id as "", name as "", job as "" FROM table
```

Comment: The OP isn't using MySQL, and you can't do this in VBA. Also, doesn't that just provide empty column names? It doesn't really get rid of them...I don't see how this is a relevant answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can run the mysql client with --skip-column-names

Comment: This is the right answer not the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that you did not indicate MySQL, at my work we use the following (MySQL) query using the ADODB reference in excel. I am posting it as you may be able to adapt it for your use:

```
Sub AdaptMeToYourUse()
  ' Connection variables
      Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
      Dim server_name As String
      Dim database_name As String
      Dim user_id As String
      Dim password As String
      Dim port_number As String

  ' Establish connection to the database
      server_name = "myserverName" ' 127.0.0.1 if running from a locally
      database_name = "myDBname" ' Enter your database name here
      user_id = "LoginName" ' enter your user ID here
      password = "PWforLoginName" ' Enter your password here
      port_number = "1234"

      Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
      conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}" _
        & ";SERVER=" & server_name _
        & ";PORT=" & port_number _
        & ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
        & ";UID=" & user_id _
        & ";PWD=" & password _
        & ";OPTION=16427" ' Option 16427 = Convert LongLong to Int

      Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

      sqlstr = "SELECT  count(" & SomeField & ") FROM " _
             & SomeTable & " WHERE " & SomeField & " = '" & var2Compare2SomeField & "' "
      rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText 'set appropriate options for you

      Worksheets("SomeWB").Range(SomeRNG).CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```