# Select data from SQL with out returning the column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I'm querying a SQL db from excel using vba, that all works fine but it also returns and displays the SQL columns headers in the excel sheet. Like this:

```
AssetTag    Machine Name    UserName    Current Site    Run Count   Defered
AssetTag    MachineName     UserName    CurrentSite     RunCount    DeferCount
B33CWM1     QRLXPB33CWM1    admin-03         QR           255          3
```

Is there a way to get VBA not to display the SQL Column headers?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359834/select-data-from-query-without-column-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ADO to create a recordset, you can use CopyFromRecordset in Excel. This does not include headers.

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```