# How to take only the value from field of the database sql?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database

I need to take only the value of field in the database. 
First i take the number of rows that my database has with this line:

```
var num = await pool.query('SELECT count(*) FROM links WHERE user_id=?',[req.user.id]);
```

But the result is this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { 'count(*)': 2 } ]
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
var num = await pool.query('SELECT count(*) FROM links WHERE user_id=?',[req.user.id]);

var num = JSON.stringify(num);
```

But the result is this:

`[{"count(*)":2}]`

And I need to take only the number, in this case, the two.

Comment: You can't have only the value. Queries return results formated like a table, with rows and columns. You can instead put an alias on your count: SELECT count(*) **as link_counter** FROM links WHERE user_id=?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data from query without column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359834/select-data-from-query-without-column-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get like this:

```
var rows = await pool.query('SELECT count(*) AS linksCount FROM links WHERE user_id=?',[req.user.id]);

var num = rows[0].linksCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var num = await pool.query('SELECT count(*) as counter FROM links WHERE user_id=?',[req.user.id]);

console.log(num);        // based on this output you will know how to get exactly the key you need

num = num[0]['counter']; // assuming the console.log() from above returned this [{"count(*)":2}]
```

Also please have in mind my comment posted directly on your question. You could try having alias as an empty string like bellow:

```
'SELECT count(*) as "" FROM links WHERE user_id=?'
```

Comment: Now the result is this: ```undefined```. How can i get the number? And if i put the alias "" the result is not the number only, the result is this ```[{"":2}]```. And i need only the number to make the for. Thanks for all

Comment: @arnaullopart please check my answer again. I removed JSON stringify line.